# ¿cómo puedo visualizar el formulario en el template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

form.py

```
from django import forms

class PreguntaForm (forms.Form):
    asunto = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True )
    descripcion = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader, Context
from django.core import serializers
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from blog.form import PreguntaForm
from django.template import RequestContext

def pregunta_crear(request):
    form = PreguntaForm()
    return render_to_response('blog/formulario.html')
    {'form': form},
    Context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

formulario.html

```
{% block title %} Crear una pregunta {% endblock %}
{% block content %}

        <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>

{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from blog.views import *
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
        #urls(r'^$', include('blog.urls')),
        url(r'^blog/templates/blog$', include('blog.urls')),
        url(r'^admin/$', admin.site.urls), # Esto no lo borres porque sino no vas a poder acceder al /admin
        url(r'^$', post_list, name='post_list'), # Si va al raiz www.tusitio.com que lo atienda el index
        url(r'^formulario/$', 'blog.views.formulario', name='formulario'), # Si ingresa en www.tusitio.com/contactos entonces sera atendido por la vista de contactos
        url(r'^tabla/$', tabla, name='tabla'), # Si ingresa en www.tusitio.com/contactos entonces sera atendido por la vista de contactos
]
```

[image: asi queda en pantalla]

Comment: Deberías mejorar el formato de la pregunta, mira cómo mejorar las preguntas aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El template no esta recibiendo form, modifica tu vista de la siguiente manera:

```
def pregunta_crear(request):
    form = PreguntaForm()
    return render(request,'blog/formulario.html'
    {'form': form,})
```

A partir de Django 2.0, render_to_response ya no se utilizara mas, continua utilizando render en su lugar.

Me confirmas si te funciona correctamente.

Comment: me sirvio muchas gracias.

Comment: @MauricioRivas Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada para que sirva a otros como confirmación de solución